# Connecting to a MYSQL Database without using TCP/IP Ports

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2010

I'm using VB2010 and MySQL to create a network software solution.

Normally, I'd use port 3306 when creating connections from the program to the database.

```
DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.2 ANSI Driver};SERVER=SERVERNAME;DATABASE=dbname;UID=root;PWD=password;OPTION=3;
```

Always works fine on my campus, its a local network program, doesn't require external access.

However, is there a way of connecting to a MySQL database without using a TCP/IP port configuration. If I ever need to distribute this software to another site, I may not always be able to get firewall rules changed to allow 3306 through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [4 ways to connect](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/connecting.html#option_general_protocol) to a mysql server:

```
protocol Value  |   Connection Protocol                             |   Permissible Operating Systems
TCP             |       TCP/IP connection to local or remote server |   All
SOCKET          |   Unix socket file connection to local server     |   Unix only
PIPE            |   Named-pipe connection to local or remote server |   Windows only
MEMORY          |   Shared-memory connection to local server        |   Windows only
```

As you can see, there are other options to connect to a mysql server, but the other methods are either platform specific or cannot be used to access remote servers. Obviously, you can also [tunnel](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204403884/tunnel-local-mysql-server-through-ssh) the mysql connection through another port. You can use tunneling on both the client and the server side. This latter one is purely a sysadmin / DBA question, so for details I would rather ask on the dba or serverfault sister sites.